# Grouping Timelapses by time difference algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, grouping

I'm trying to write a program that groups Timelapse photo's together from their timestamp. The timelapse photo's and random photo's are in one folder.

For example, if the timestamp difference in seconds between the previous and current photo is: 346, 850, 13, 14, 13, 14, 15, 12, 12, 13, 16, 11, 438.

You can make a reasonable guess the timelapse began at 13 and ended at 11.

Right now I'm trying a hacky solution to compare the percentage difference with the previous one.

**But there has to be a formula/algo to group timestamps together by timedifference. Rolling mean or something.**

Am I looking over a simple solution? 
Thank you!

def cat_algo(folder):

```
# Get a list with all the CR2 files in the folder we are processing
file_list = folder_to_file_list(folder)

# Extract the timestamp out of the CR2 file into a sorted dictionary
cr2_timestamp = collections.OrderedDict()
for file in file_list:
    cr2_timestamp[file] = return_date_from_raw(file)
    print str(file) + " - METADATA TIMESTAMP: " + \
        str(return_date_from_raw(file))

# Loop over the dictionary to compare the timestamps and create a new dictionary with a suspected group number per shot
# Make sure we know that there is no first file yet using this (can be refractored)
item_count = 1
group_count = 0
cr2_category = collections.OrderedDict()
# get item and the next item out of the sorted dictionary
for item, nextitem in zip(cr2_timestamp.items(), cr2_timestamp.items()[1::]):

    # if not the first CR2 file
    if item_count >= 2:
        current_date_stamp = item[1]
        next_date_stamp = nextitem[1]

        delta_previous = current_date_stamp - previous_date_stamp
        delta_next = next_date_stamp - current_date_stamp

        try:
            difference_score = int(delta_next.total_seconds() /
                                   delta_previous.total_seconds() * 100)
            print "diffscore: " + str(difference_score)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print "zde"

        if delta_previous > datetime.timedelta(minutes=5):
            # if difference_score < 20:
            print item[0] + " - hit - " + str(delta_previous)
            group_count += 1
            cr2_category[item[0]] = group_count
        else:
            cr2_category[item[0]] = group_count

            # create a algo to come up with percentage difference and use this to label timelapses.
        print int(delta_previous.total_seconds())
        print int(delta_next.total_seconds())

        # Calculations done, make the current date stamp the previous datestamp for the next iteration
        previous_date_stamp = current_date_stamp

        # If time difference with previous over X make a dict with name:number, in the end everything which has the
        # same number 5+ times in a row can be assumed as a timelapse.

    else:
        # If it is the first date stamp, assign it the current one to be used in the next loop
        previous_date_stamp = item[1]

    # To help make sure this is not the first image in the sequence.
    item_count += 1

print cr2_category
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use itertools.groupby, using a function that returns True if the delay meets your criteria for timelapse photo regions, based on the list of delays, you can get the index of each such region. Basically, we're grouping on the True/False output of that function.

```
from itertools import groupby

# time differences given in original post
data = [346, 850, 13, 14, 13, 14, 15, 12, 12, 13, 16, 11, 438]

MAX_DELAY = 25 # timelapse regions will have a delay no larger than this
MIN_LENGTH = 3 # timelapse regions will have at least this many photos

index = 0
for timelapse, g in groupby(data, lambda x: x <= MAX_DELAY):
    length = len(list(g))
    if (timelapse and length > MIN_LENGTH):
        print ('timelapse index {}, length {}'.format(index, length))
    index += length
```

output:

> timelapse index 2, length 10

Comment: adjust parameters to taste

Comment: Thank you, however if the the input is a sorted dictionary with multiple timelapses contained in it what can I adjust to get the above working? 

For example the dict. can contain a timelapse with 45 seconds difference between shots and also a timelapse with 2 seconds difference.

Comment: Sounds like a different question. Might want to post it with some example data and tag me in a comment. Depending on the precision, and how close their snapshots are in milliseconds, it might be possible to detect with the period (with few false positives), or impossible. But it would be much smarter to solve it in advance -- put some camera metadata in there, or give different cameras their own folder. (Are you dissatisfied with the answer for this question?)

Comment: Maybe the situation I described was too simplified. I'll post again with a real world example. I think it can be solved by looking at the percentage difference (over a sequence or the previous photo?) instead of time difference and knowing that a timelapse always consists out of 5+ photo's in sequence with a minimal variance in time difference. Some false positives is not a huge problem. 

There are better ways to solve it practically during the offload process and with metadata, but in this case it is about sorting timelapses which are already offloaded using a script.

Comment: Can't tag you so here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688708/grouping-photos-to-timelapse-by-time-stamp-algorithm thank you for your help so far.